# React Native canvas in WebView

Tags: javascript, android, canvas, webview, react-native

I'm trying to code a "paint" Android app with React Native 0.17.

I have a `Canvas` component (strongly inspired by 
[react-native-canvas](https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-canvas)) :

```
import React from 'react-native';
import Paint from '../utils/paint'

var {
  View,
  WebView
} = React;

const Canvas = React.createClass({

  render() {
    return (
      <WebView
        html={Paint}
        style={this.props.style}
        javaScriptEnabledAndroid={true}
      />
    );
  },

});

export default Canvas;
```

and a `Paint` component that I use in the `html` props of the `WebView` in the `Canvas` component above.

This component is nothing more than a very long string containing HTML and JS that come from this tuto : [creating-a-paint-application-with-html5-canvas](http://codetheory.in/creating-a-paint-application-with-html5-canvas/)

```
export default `<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <h1 id='toto'>TATA</h1>

    <br />

    <div id="sketch">
      <canvas id="paint" style='border: 1px solid black'></canvas>
    </div>

    <script>
      (function() {
        var canvas = document.querySelector('#paint');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        var sketch = document.querySelector('#sketch');
        var sketch_style = getComputedStyle(sketch);
        canvas.width = parseInt(sketch_style.getPropertyValue('width'));
        canvas.height = parseInt(sketch_style.getPropertyValue('height'));

        var mouse = {x: 0, y: 0};

        var start_events = ["mousedown", "touchstart"];
        var move_events = ["mousemove", "touchmove"];
        var end_events = ["mouseup", "touchend"];

        /* Mouse Capturing Work */
        move_events.forEach(function(event) {
          canvas.addEventListener(event, function(e) {
            mouse.x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
            mouse.y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
          }, false);
        });

        /* Drawing on Paint App */
        ctx.lineWidth = 5;
        ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
        ctx.lineCap = 'round';
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'back';

        start_events.forEach(function(event) {
          canvas.addEventListener(event, function(e) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);

            move_events.forEach(function(me){ canvas.addEventListener(me, onPaint, false); });
          }, false);
        });


        end_events.forEach(function(event) {
          canvas.addEventListener(event, function(e) {
            move_events.forEach(function(me){ canvas.removeEventListener(me, onPaint, false); });
          }, false);
        });


        var onPaint = function() {
          ctx.lineTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
          ctx.stroke();
        };

      }());
    </script>
  </body>
</html>`;
```

My HTML/JS works well in a brower (Chrome) but unfortunately I'm not able to draw anything in my React Native app.

Can someone help me ? 
Which events should I listen in React Native ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ES6 template string seems to break when you comment some lines of JS in your `<script>` tag.

Try remove them:

```
export default `<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <h1 id='toto'>TATA</h1>

    <br />

    <div id="sketch">
      <canvas id="paint" style='border: 1px solid black'></canvas>
    </div>

    <script>
      (function() {
        var canvas = document.querySelector('#paint');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        var sketch = document.querySelector('#sketch');
        var sketch_style = getComputedStyle(sketch);
        canvas.width = parseInt(sketch_style.getPropertyValue('width'));
        canvas.height = parseInt(sketch_style.getPropertyValue('height'));

        var mouse = {x: 0, y: 0};

        var start_events = ["mousedown", "touchstart"];
        var move_events = ["mousemove", "touchmove"];
        var end_events = ["mouseup", "touchend"];

        move_events.forEach(function(event) {
          canvas.addEventListener(event, function(e) {
            mouse.x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
            mouse.y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
          }, false);
        });

        ctx.lineWidth = 5;
        ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
        ctx.lineCap = 'round';
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'back';

        start_events.forEach(function(event) {
          canvas.addEventListener(event, function(e) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);

            move_events.forEach(function(me){ canvas.addEventListener(me, onPaint, false); });
          }, false);
        });


        end_events.forEach(function(event) {
          canvas.addEventListener(event, function(e) {
            move_events.forEach(function(me){ canvas.removeEventListener(me, onPaint, false); });
          }, false);
        });


        var onPaint = function() {
          ctx.lineTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
          ctx.stroke();
        };

      }());
    </script>
  </body>
</html>`;
```

Answer (score 2):

`react-native-canvas` current maintainer here, to people coming here looking for a canvas solution for React Native: I want to let you know `react-native-canvas` today is a stable solution which is very different from the code injection hack it used to be.

Answer (score 0):

[@flyskywhy/react-native-gcanvas](https://github.com/flyskywhy/react-native-gcanvas) is a C++ native canvas component based on gpu opengl glsl shader, runs well on Android and iOS. You can see [Performance Test Result](https://github.com/flyskywhy/react-native-gcanvas#performance-test-result), and an easily `<canvas/>` ported example [react-native-particles-bg](https://github.com/flyskywhy/react-native-particles-bg) runs on Android, iOS and Web.